# Типизация array.filter в typescript

Tags: typescript

**Пример:**

```
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 4];

const filteredList: string[] = list.filter((i) => typeof i === 'string');
```

**Проблема:**

Типизация для filtered не верная и typescript ругается на нее. Якобы отфильтрованный список не соответствует типу массива строк. Знаю что есть возможность приведения типов, но ведь прописывать типы как `as string[]` плохая практика.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста, как типизировать правильно, что бы не было ошибок ts?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо так: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBANgS2jAvDA2gcgIaYDQyYBG+hwpALALoDcAUKJLAGYJxQCmAThwCYAySWGkTQAdK3bcAFNIAeASgBcMOTCQxoXBGADmqAHwwoATwAOHEM1WoUaTFp27MCmkA)

```
const list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 4];
const filteredList = list.filter((x): x is string => typeof x === 'string');
```

Тип получается верный - массив строк.